Why is the gradient of $S = X \cdot W + b$, $dS$, equal to $\frac{\text{probs} - 1} {N}$, where $\text{probs}$ is the softmax classifier of $S$?
Why is the gradient of $S = X \cdot W + b$, $dS$, equal to $\frac{\text{probs} - 1} {N}$?
Here, probs is a $1 \times K$ array which represents the probabilities that $X_i$ belongs to class $k$, where $k = 1, 2, ..., K$ and $N$ is the size of the dataset.
$X_i$ has $J$ features/columns ($X_{i1}$, $X_{i2}$, ... ,$X_{iJ}$) and we use the softmax activation function on $S$:
$$\text{probs}_k =  \frac{\exp(S_K)}{\sum_{k = 1}^{K} \exp(S_k)}$$
Here is the specific part of the code which states that $dS = \frac{\text{probs} - 1} {N}$: 
Here is the structure of the NN:

Edit: I found the answer here: https://towardsdatascience.com/derivative-of-the-softmax-function-and-the-categorical-cross-entropy-loss-ffceefc081d1
